# map Postgres ltree value to recursive struct

Tags: postgresql, go

I am designing a comment reply model in golang and Postgres, and my comment table looks like this.

```
create TABLE comments(postid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
                comment TEXT,
                comment_reaction VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                commented_user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                created_at TIMESTAMP,
                parent_path ltree ,
                CONSTRAINT fk_post FOREIGN KEY(postid)
                REFERENCES posts(postid) on DELETE CASCADE);
```

I have added a couple of values to the table and my selection goes as below:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_path <@ 'ed9f0f769ee4455b8dbf6120afc902fa';
                postid                | comment  | comment_reaction | commented_user |         created_at         |             parent_path              
--------------------------------------+----------+------------------+----------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------
 ed9f0f76-9ee4-455b-8dbf-6120afc902fa | blah1    |                  | sai            | 2021-02-06 16:46:36.436241 | ed9f0f769ee4455b8dbf6120afc902fa
 ed9f0f76-9ee4-455b-8dbf-6120afc902fa | reply1   |                  | sai            | 2003-02-01 00:00:00        | ed9f0f769ee4455b8dbf6120afc902fa.1
 ed9f0f76-9ee4-455b-8dbf-6120afc902fa | reply2   |                  | sai            | 2003-02-01 00:00:00        | ed9f0f769ee4455b8dbf6120afc902fa.2
 ed9f0f76-9ee4-455b-8dbf-6120afc902fa | reply1.1 |                  | sai            | 2003-02-01 00:00:00        | ed9f0f769ee4455b8dbf6120afc902fa.1.2
```

so basically I have some post with id

which has a comment. `blah1` whose replies are `reply 1` and `reply 2` and reply 1 has sub reply `reply1.1`

How do I map it to a struct in go such that I get a JOSN output as below

```
{
    post :ed9f0f76-9ee4-455b-8dbf-6120afc902fa,
    comment :blah
    reply1 :{
           comment:reply1,
            reply: {
            comment :reply1.1
                   }
    }
   reply2 :{
          comment:reply2,
        }
}
```

so this can go to n comment and reply, is it even possible in the first place to reconstruct the JSON mapping in go? and if yes can someone help me? Alternate solutions for a schema and reconstruction are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i figured a solution myself while trying to understand facebook schema.
facebook shows the first level comments and shows the replies but replies are hidden.
so we can do BFS on the tree

```
 SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_path ~ 'be785c64e9654a59821d20dff67230fc.*{1,1}';
```

this gives us first level children, which i can map to a struct and show the replies for each child as count

Then if user wants to dig in he can make another api call with the child node.
This way performance is also preserved. mapping entire tree to struct recursively will also affect the performance.